# Limiting the number of edges to a vertex in a randomly generated graph

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I have a generated a random un-directed graph using Boost graph library.

I add the number of vertices and edges randomly as follow:

```
RNGType rng( time(0) );
    boost::uniform_int<> one_to_four( 1, (N-1) );
    boost::variate_generator< RNGType, boost::uniform_int<> >gen(rng, one_to_four);
    for(int i =0; i<(N-1); i++)
    {
        int k = 0;
        while(k<4)
        //while(k<(N/2))
        {  
            int n  = gen();
            // Adding edges onto graph

            if(!boost::edge(i, n, g).second && !boost::edge(n, i, g).second)    
                {
                if(i !=n )
                {       
                add_edge(i, n, g);
                k++;
                }
                }
        }
    }
```

As it can seen, i limit the number of edges to 4 using `while(k<4)` but it works only for incoming edges. I want to limit both incoming and outgoing edges to 4. For example if I enter the number of vertex to be 10 i get:

```
graph G{
0;
1;
2;
3;
4;
5;
6;
7;
8;
9;
0--1 ;
0--2 ;
0--2 ;
0--2 ;
1--3 ;
2--1 ;
2--4 ;
3--2 ;
3--2 ;
3--4 ;
3--0 ;
4--1 ;
4--9 ;
4--8 ;
5--
and so on..
}
```

As it can be seen there are already 4 outgoing edges from 0 and there is an incoming edge from (3,0), hence the number of edged leaving and entering the vertex 0 becomes 5, I want to restrict it to just 4 or maybe less but not more than 4.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request the number of incoming and outgoing edges for a node with `in_degree` and `out_degree`.

If you initialise `k` to be `in_degree(i, g) + out_degree(i, g)` instead of 0, you'll ensure you'll take into account edges already added for node i.

You'll also want to check before adding the edge between i and n that `(in_degree(n) + out_degree(n) + 1) <= 4`.  That will make sure you don't add too many edges to one of the random nodes.

Comment: thanks a lot mate. But what about my while? should it be while(k<4)?

Comment: Yep, that's right.  So k represents the number of edges on node i.  You start counting from however many edges it already has, then keep adding edges until you have 4.

Comment: Due to some reason, when i included you code, I get nothing in the output. My graphs are not created.

Comment: Hi some one of the vertices remain unconnected to other vertices, how can i resolve it?

Comment: If you only increment k when you successfully add a new edge, then you'll keep trying to add edges until there are 4 edges linking node i.    Perhaps your graph is actually directed, in which case you'll need to insert back-edges too (`add_edge(i,n,g); add_edge(n,i,g);`).  Sorry, don't have boost in my environment at the moment, so can't try this myself.